# Form entry table search results in opening a new page and error

Tags: php

Shoots me to the /index.php with a error 404. I don't want it to navigate to another page, just display the results in a table.

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong, I just started php and have been using w3 to navigate the syntax. I managed to make a plugin that would display the a entire table but now I am trying to use a form to search a table and display the results.

```
...
if( isset($_GET['submit']) ){
    $ssterm = $_POST["name"];
    $query = "SELECT  ID, Retailer, City, State, Contact, Address1, Address2, Country, Zip, Email, Website FROM Stores WHERE Retailer LIKE '%" . $rssterm .  "%' OR City LIKE '%" . $ssterm ."%'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
    echo "<table>
               <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Retailer</th>
                  <th>City</th>
                  <th>State</th>
                  <th>Contact</th>
                  <th>Address1</th>
                  <th>Address2</th>
                  <th>Country</th>
                  <th>Zip</th>
                  <th>Email</th>
                  <th>Website</th>
              </tr>";


      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
      echo "<tr><td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Retailer'] . "</td><td>" . $row['City'] . "</td><td>" . $row['State'] . "</td><td>" .
      $row['Contact'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Address1'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Address2'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Zip'] .
      "</td><td>" . $row['Email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Website'] . "</td></tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
      }

      echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
    }
else {
  echo "No Results Found...";
}
}
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="searchform">
  <input  type="text" name="name">
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
</form>

<?php
$conn->close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
} // end of a shortcode brace
?>
```

I thought this would for sure work, but it just shoots me to the /index.php with a error 404. I don't want it to navigate to another page, just display the results in a table. I am using this on a wordpress site and as a plugin using a shortcode to implement it into a page.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error, it means the URL in the `action` attribute of the form is wrong. It has nothing to do with the PHP.

Comment: It should be `$_POST['submit']`, not `$_GET['submit']`.

Comment: @Barmar I kind of thought so, but I have no clue how to fix it. I thought $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] made it call the current php script

Comment: @Dharman ah okay gotcha.

Comment: @Dharman this is really helpful thank you

Comment: Yes, it should. Check your server access log to see what URL is actually causing the 404 error.

Comment: @Barmar ``POST /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 8542`` and then the link for the page that it is on.

Comment: What do you see in the `action` attribute if you use `View Source`?

Comment: @Barmar oh the strange the action in view source shows ``/index.php`` ??

Comment: What happens if you replace `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` with the actual URL of the form?

Comment: @Barmar I get a 404 error but its on the same page and not index anymore.

Comment: I don't see how that can be, if you were able to open the form with the same URL.

Comment: @Barmar I tried the full path and short one, soon as I hit search Error 404 pops up, even though its the same url.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your server configuration, maybe it's doing rewrites for `POST` requests differently than `GET`.